# Netbeans java applet project screen popping up

Tags: java, file, netbeans, applet, project

Im a beginner in java. Tried using NetBeans for this example code:

```
    import java.applet.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class Damn extends Applet
{
  public void paint (Graphics g)
  {
        g.drawString("Hello World!", 50, 25);
  }
}
```

Created a java applet file for this and when I run it, it keeps popping up a screen that says- "NewMain class wasn't found in damn project"

How do I fix it? run it?

Comment: 1) Don't use a tool (i.e. Netbeans) that you do not understand. 2) That was not the error message.  Please copy/paste instead of paraphrasing messages in future. 3) A newbie should not be coding GUIs, let alone applets. 4) When you get enough experience to code GUIs, use Swing components rather than AWT.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code for create the minimum applet :

```
import javax.swing.JApplet;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.JLabel;

public class HelloWorld extends JApplet {
    //Called when this applet is loaded into the browser.
    public void init() {
        //Execute a job on the event-dispatching thread; creating this applet's GUI.
        try {
            SwingUtilities.invokeAndWait(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    JLabel lbl = new JLabel("Hello World");
                    add(lbl);
                }
            });
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.err.println("createGUI didn't complete successfully");
        }
    }
}
```

If you are new to Java applet you should follow this [link](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/applet/).

By the way applet is an old techno no one use it anymore... they have proved their weakness by the past...

Answer (score 0):

Instead of running the project, run that particular file. (To do so, right click anywhere in file and select 'Run File').
I know this may not be the best way, but it worked in my case.